# NullPointerException when trying to read a double from a json file

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception

I am trying to read a `json` file, and from it, a double, but I came across `NullPointerException` in the following situation, while there is no apparent error in it.

```
double longitude = (double) json_restaurant.get("longitude");
```

error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I tried to check if it wasn't working, by calling `System.out.println(longitude)` after the above-mentioned code snippet, and the terminal does display the correct value of `longitude`.

Where am I going wrong, if anywhere?

Comment: Consider editing this question, it does not read very clearly.

Comment: `I tried to check if it wasn't working, by calling System.out.println(longitude) after the above-mentioned code snippet,` - well that would imply the error is not thrown in that line of code if it runs past it?

Comment: how is json_restaurant created?

Answer (score 0):

Check the JSON. Does it have the `longitude`? If it does not `get("longitude")` might return `null`. It is something that you can not assign to primitive `double`. That will throw `NPE`.

Try using `Double` instead